# Facebook login using Facebook-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

New to PHP and just downloaded Facebook-PHP-SDK and I already created an app on Facebook developers and now I am trying to implement this login code that I got from the following line, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login, but I keep getting an error, so any help would be appreciated! I have omitted my app ID and app secret.

Error Message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_start() in /usr/home/north/Facebook/login.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /usr/home/north/Facebook/login.php on line 2
```

login.php

```
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

fb-callback.php

```
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just needed to delete the line session_start() and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check phpinfo(); to see if the session is enabled or not.